# responding with multiple JSON renders. (Ruby/Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, model-view-controller, controller

This is a relatively simple one and I'm pretty sure its just syntax.

Im trying to render multiple objects as json as a response in a controller. So something like this:

```
  def info
    @allWebsites = Website.all
    @allPages = Page.all
    @allElementTypes = ElementType.all
    @allElementData = ElementData.all


    respond_to do |format|
      format.json{render :json => @allWebsites}
      format.json{render :json =>@allPages}  
      format.json{render :json =>@allElementTypes}  
      format.json{render :json =>@allElementData}
      end
    end
  end
```

Problem is I'm only getting a single json back and its always the top one. Is there any way to render multiple objects this way?

Or should I create a new object made up of other objects.to_json?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you could actually do it like so:

```
format.json {
   render :json => {
      :websites => @allWebsites,
      :pages => @allPages,
      :element_types => @AllElementTypes,
      :element_data => @AllElementData
   }
}
```

in case you use jquery you will need to do something like:

```
data = $.parseJSON( xhr.responseText );
data.websites #=> @allWebsites data from your controller
data.pages #=> @allPages data from your controller
```

and so on

EDIT:

answering your question, you don't necessarily have to parse the response, it's just what I usually do. There's a number of functions that do it for you right away, for example:

```
$.getJSON('/info', function(data) {
  var websites = data.websites,
      pages = data.pages,
      ...

});
```

Comment: With regards to the Jquery I just want to clarify do you mean that I will have to parse the json back into seperate json elements when its received from the server?

Comment: That's what it looks like to me. Sounds reasonable.

Comment: Correct - the response has to be *one* json object... you can then break it down further after you get the response.  That's why rails was only sending one and ignoring the others - You can only send one!

Comment: how do I do `:element => @element, :only => [:id, :property], :include => :assoc`?