# Json result with model and string value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I m trying to return both a active record model and a string value in json but not able to do so

Here is my controller/action

```
 def index
    @accounts = Account.search(params[:search_login])
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @accounts, :miles => "23"}
    end
end
```

And here is Ajax Call

```
    function GetMiles()
{
  $.ajax({url: "/accounts?" + "search_login=" + $('#account_number').val(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( data ) {
        alert(data.miles)
        response($.map(data.acc, function( item1 ) {
          alert(item.account_number)
        }
      });
}
```

But not able to get miles value as well any model property value, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i have found the solution here

[responding with multiple JSON renders. (Ruby/Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995660/responding-with-multiple-json-renders-ruby-rails)

thanks Stack Overflow